# Elasticsearch: avoid to return "sort" value in the resultset

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch, overflow

I have this simple search:

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 5,
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "_source": [
     "info"
   ],
   "sort": {
      "date": {
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
}
```

and the resultset is:

```
"hits":{
  "hits":[
    {"sort":[-9223372036854775808 ], "_type": "reports", "_source": …},
    {"sort":[-9223372036854775808 ], "_type": "reports", "_source": …},
    {"sort":[-9223372036854775808 ], "_type": "reports", "_source": …},
    {"sort":[-9223372036854775808 ], "_type": "reports", "_source": …},
    {"sort":[-9223372036854775808 ], "_type": "reports", "_source": …}
  ],
  "total": 38,
  "max_score": null
},
"_shards":{
  "successful": 15,
  "failed": 0,
  "total": 15
},
"took": 11,
"timed_out": false
```

Is it possible to remove the fields `"sort":[-9223372036854775808 ]` from the resultset? I have to create a json with this result and I got an error (`json_decode(): integer overflow detected`) because of this big integer inside this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely not return the `sort` by using [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) in your query.

In the URL of your query, simply add the following query string parameter:

```
...&filter_path=hits.hits._source,hits.hits._id,hits.hits._type,hits.hits._index
```

and you'll get all the JSON fields inside each hit, except the `sort` one.

Comment: is there another method? Currently I can do only POST request to ES and I have no direct access to this type of arguments, I can change only the body of the request!

Comment: You can also add query string parameters in the URL you POST, even though you also send a payload in the body. Feasible?

Comment: no, I cannot send additional post data to ES but the index and the search body :(

Comment: Can you show how you're sending your query, please?

Comment: I'm currently using an internal API that accepts only two params: the index where to search and the search body to forward to ES (the one I pasted in the question before)

Comment: Where is the `json_decode` call done? In your code or in that internal API?

Comment: in my code, I did the json_decode on the result I receive from the API. right now I resolved doing a str_replace on the result before do the json_decode, but I'm looking for something better :D

Comment: I was going to suggest that as a hack :) It seems that it's a [common issue](https://www.google.ch/search?q=json_decode()%3A+integer+overflow+detected) which isn't solved yet.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and time, I'll do in that way waiting for an improvement on our internal API :)

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the best way.